# Detect Function call or Transaction when no Event is Emitted

Tags: events

Is it possible to detect a contract function call using a listener, even though it does not explicitly emit an event? I want to think this is possible, because block explorers like Etherscan are able to detect functions calls/transactions, as well as their metadata, such as block hash, value, caller, etc, even when the function called does not emit an event.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the data of the transaction. The data for a function call starts with the function signature (4 bytes), followed by the parameters of the function. If you want to see if a transaction called the `transfer` function of a token for example, you take the first four bytes of `keccak256("transfer(address,uint256)")` = `0xa9059cbb`. Then you can simply check if the function data starts with those four bytes.